# Finding a lightweight wallet

Tags: wallets

I'm looking for a lightweight wallet. I can't find one listed on the site. Just the full node. What are your recommendations.

Answer (score 1):

Metamask is probably you're best bet, I find it's the most user friendly without sacrificing functionality. You can also use MyEtherWallet but it is significantly less user friendly. Exodus is another option (but you might not be able to use all ERC20 tokens, consult exodus documentation for the details)

https://metamask.io/

Comment: /High Five! I do reviews and check the community. I'm happy to report that you guys are doing great! :)